# Javascript match dont include

Tags: javascript, regex, match

String:

```
<row>1</row>
<row>2</row>
```

Regex:

```
<row>([\s\S]*?)<\/row>/gm
```

Results:

```
["<row>1</row>", "<row>2</row>"]
```

Desired Results

```
["1", "2"]
```

Comment: Your using match[0] instead of match[1] (assuming your using .exec)

Comment: I am not I am using .match(/<row>([\s\S]*?)<\/row>/gm)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/6wnd3rbn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is  an example: http://jsfiddle.net/zgdksaax/

```
var pattern = /<row>([\s\S]*?)<\/row>/gm;
var string = "<row>1</row><row>2</row>";
console.log(string.replace(pattern, "$1").split("")) // ["1", "2"]
```